# Google Apps script created file is not PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a PDF file with this code:

```
var name = "test.pdf";
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + newSpreadsheetID + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
  '&size=A4' + 
  '&portrait=true' + 
  '&fitw=true' +       // fit to width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' +
  '&gridlines=false' + 
  '&fzr=false' +       // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
  '&gid='+SheetID;       //the sheet's Id

  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var pdf = pdf.getBlob().setName(name);

  DocsList.createFile(pdf);
```

This code creates a file but the file contains just plain text, can you guys help me to get it into PDF format?

Comment: So does it create a .txt file or .pdf file?

Comment: It says .pdf in Google drive but it has just a blue icon and when I open it, it contains alot of text

Comment: The text file contains a HTML file

Answer (score 0):

First off, DocsList was deprecated (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list). So I think we should use DriveApp this time.

I ignored the parameters you used to format the pdf, the script can be simply as -

```
var sheet = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
DriveApp.createFile(sheet.getAs("application/pdf"));
```

Please let me know if you want more elaboration. :)

Comment: That worked, but I get gridlines with this solution. How can I get rid of those? :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes and got your call working. I don't know where the documentation for the export settings are, but some of them don't work such as "gridlines".  Also below is a 2 line example of the same thing.

```
function makePDF(){

var newSpreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
var SheetID="Sheet1";

var name = "test.pdf";
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + newSpreadsheetID + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'; +
  '&size=A4' + 
  '&portrait=true' + 
  '&fitw=true' +       // fit to width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' +
  '&gridlines=false' + 
  '&fzr=false'; +       // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
  '&gid='+SheetID;       //the sheet's Id

var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{headers: {authentication:"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions:true}).getBlob();
  pdf.setName(name);
DriveApp.createFile(pdf);

}

function simplePDFConvert(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( spreadSheetId );
     DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
}
```